# Time-dependent vector field induced by isotopy (definition clarification)

Tags: differential-geometry, symplectic-geometry

I hope this is not a duplicate, but I can't really find a satisfactory answer to this question (although there are a few closely sounded questions).

Let $M$ be a (smooth) manifold and $\rho: M \times \mathbb{R} \to M$ an isotopy (so every $\rho_t := \rho(-,t)$ is a diffeomorphism $M \to M$). Then $\rho$ induces a time-dependent vector field $v_t$ by the formula
$$v_t(x) = \frac{d}{ds} \rho_s(\rho_t^{-1}(x)) \Bigg|_{s=t}$$
The question is that I don't really understand what this formula is trying to say in any technical sense. Let me explain.

Fix some $t \in \mathbb{R}$. By definition, a vector field is a section $M \to TM$ of the projection $\pi: TM \to M$, so we want the expression $\frac{d}{ds} \rho_s(\rho_t^{-1}(x)) \Bigg|_{s=t}$ to give an element in $T_xM$. For a point $x \in M$, we now think of $\rho_s(\rho_t^{-1}(x))$ as a map $\mathbb{R} \to M$ in the variable $s$. Now take the derivative at $s=t$, we obtain a map of tangent spaces
$$\frac{d}{ds} \rho_s(\rho_t^{-1}(x)) \Bigg|_{s=t}: \mathbb{R} \to T_{\rho_t(\rho_t^{-1}(x))} M = T_x M$$
instead of an element $T_x M$. Am I supposed to evaluate this map at $t$, or am I misunderstanding something?

Note: I use Guillemin-Pollack's definition of derivative, in case you wonder.

Comment: In general, for any vector space $V$ over a field $\Bbb{F}$, evaluation at $1\in\Bbb{F}$ gives a canonical isomorphism $\text{Hom}(\Bbb{F},V)\cong V$, i.e $T\mapsto T(1)$ (with the inverse map obviously being $v\in V\mapsto [x\in\Bbb{F}\mapsto xv\in V]$). And anyway if you wanted to be super strict, you should have said that it is a map $T_t\Bbb{R}\to T_xM$, and so to get an element of $T_xM$, you should evaluate on $1_t\in T_t\Bbb{R}$, the tangent vector at $t$ corresponding to $1\in\Bbb{R}$, under the isomorphism $T_t\Bbb{R}\cong\Bbb{R}$.